# Laravel: How to get key of collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this properties table

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_name  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_value | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_group | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I retrieve all values and group them by `meta_group`

Controller

```
 public function properties()
 {
   $properties = Properties::all()->groupBy('meta_group');
   return view('dashboard.properties.index')->with('properties', $properties);
 }
```

`$properties` contains:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2953
     all: [
       "points" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2955
         all: [
           App\Properties {#2964
             id: 1,
             user_id: 3,
             meta_name: "point_interval",
             meta_value: "1",
             meta_group: "points",
             created_at: null,
             updated_at: null,
           },
           App\Properties {#2963
             id: 2,
             user_id: 3,
             meta_name: "point_amount",
             meta_value: "1",
             meta_group: "points",
             created_at: null,
             updated_at: null,
           },
         ],
       },
       "message" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2949
         all: [
           App\Properties {#2965
             id: 3,
             user_id: 3,
             meta_name: "message_length",
             meta_value: "10",
             meta_group: "message",
             created_at: null,
             updated_at: null,
           },
           App\Properties {#2966
             id: 4,
             user_id: 3,
             meta_name: "message_score",
             meta_value: "90",
             meta_group: "message",
             created_at: null,
             updated_at: null,
           },
         ],
       },
     ],
   }
```

In blade I do this

```
@foreach($properties as $group=>$property)
  {{$group}} 
@endforeach
```

Which outputs `points`, then `messages` as I'd expect.

Then I want to output the key name and the value e.g. `meta_name:message_score`

But when I do

```
@foreach($property as $key=>$prop)
  {{$prop}}
@endforeach
```

`$prop` outputs 2 objects

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 3,
    "meta_name": "point_interval",
    "meta_value": "1",
    "meta_group": "points",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
} {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 3,
    "meta_name": "point_amount",
    "meta_value": "1",
    "meta_group": "points",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
```

So then I try to get each key name

```
@foreach($prop as $ke => $pr)
  {{$ke}}
@endforeach
```

But that outputs

```
incrementing exists wasRecentlyCreated timestamps incrementing exists wasRecentlyCreated timestamps
```

and `{{$pr}}` outputs `1 1 1 1 1 1`

I can't go any further down with the `foreach()` as it errors out.

How can I print the key name and value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I can do this to get a normal array instead of a collection and then it works

```
$properties = Properties::all()->groupBy('meta_group')->toArray();
```

Comment: Or in blade `@for ($i = 0; $i < count($properties); $i++)/* $i code*/@endfor`.